# php - mysql different query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I had a category table as follows

```
id     |    name       |  parent_of    |   created_on
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
1      |   Name 1      |  0            |  2013-05-1 00:00:00
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
2      |   Name 2      |  0            |  2013-05-1 00:00:00
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
3      |   Name 3      |  1            |  2013-05-1 00:00:00
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
4      |   Name 4      |  1            |  2013-05-1 00:00:00
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
5      |   Name 5      |  3            |  2013-05-1 00:00:00
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
6      |   Name 6      |  3            |  2013-05-1 00:00:00
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
```

As in the table some category has child categories.

In this table as follows. Specifying the table id

```
1
  |--> 3
  |   |--> 5
  |   |--> 6
  |--> 4
2
```

My question is while adding a product, need to select the category for each product. But only need to show the end category. ie need not showing id 1 and 3 since it is not the end. Only need to show 5,6,4 and 2 ( those are the categories with out any category according the list )

Can any one please help me with the MySQL query for listing the category drop down ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that, this is what you want.

```
SELECT id FROM category where ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT parent_of FROM category) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: yes .. that worked .. thanks... but how to make a list as shown ? that tree ? can you please help ?

Comment: the tree for complete navigation through categories. Like I mentioned in my question

Comment: yes ... that showing the end category working fine ... but I need to show a tree like above ... can you please help ?

Comment: then your have to frame an array like this,
array(1=>array(3,4), 2, 3=>array(5,6), 4, 5, 6);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891355/php-mysql-create-a-tree-view-from-product-table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.* FROM categories c 
LEFT JOIN categories c1 ON c.id = c1.parent_of
WHERE c1.id IS NULL
```